# Spring and Thymeleaf: Sending an object to a controller from a th:each table

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am making a table of experience data using the **th:each** attribute with **Thymeleaf** and my goal is to have a submit button in each row that, when clicked, will send an experience object to my controller that corresponds with the row I clicked the submit button in.

I have no idea whats wrong and can't seem to find anything online to help with this problem.

Here is my section of webpage code:

```
<div th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(borrower.experiences)}">
    <h2>List of Experiences</h2>
    <!--  <form ACTION="#" th:action="@{/initiate-edit}" th:object="${experience}"
      method="POST">-->
        <table id="your-table-id">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Edit Buttons</td>
                <th>Date Planted</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Dept</th>
                <th>Resolution</th>
                <th>Source</th>
                <th>Last Update Date</th>
                <th>Last Update Name</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr th:each="experience : ${borrower.experiences}">       
                <td>
                  <form ACTION="#" th:action="@{/initiate-edit}" 
                    th:object="${experience}" method="POST">
                    <!--<a th:href="@{/initiate-edit/}">CLICK</a>-->
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                </td>
                <td th:text="${experience.experienceDate}">13/01/2014</td>
                <td th:text="${experience.rating}">4</td>
                <td th:text="${experience.categoryShortDesc}">Account and Billing</td>
                <td th:text="${experience.deptDesc}">Account and Billing</td>
                <td th:text="${experience.resolutionShortTx}">Account and Billing</td>
                <td th:text="${experience.source}">Account and Billing</td>
                <td th:text="${experience.lastUpdateDate}">Account and Billing</td>
                <td th:text="${experience.lastUpdatedName}">Account and Billing</td>
                <td th:text="${experience.commentsShort}">Account and Billing</td>    
              </tr>             
            </tbody>
       </table>    
</div>
```

Here is the method I am sending it to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/initiate-edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String initiateEdit(@AuthenticationPrincipal final User user, 
                               @ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")CustomerExperience editableExperience, final Model model) {

        LOG.info("THIS IS A TEST!!!" + editableExperience.getSsn());

        model.addAttribute("editableExperience", editableExperience);

        return EDIT_PAGE;

    }
```

Comment: You should describe what your problem is. From what I can see you submit a form that sends no data. To start off the data you want to submit should be **inside** your form.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first post on Stack Overflow so I'm still trying to figure out how it all works lol. 

But my problem is that I am trying to send the "experience" object (located within my th:object tag) to my controller method. I want access to the entire object itself not just the data rows that are being created in the table. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes I understand, check out *Aeseir*'s answer, it's what I was talking about. Although I must say i'd do it using javascript

Answer (score 4):

You need to fill your form with inputs as the inputs get sent:

```
<form ACTION="#" th:action="@{/initiate-edit}" th:object="${experience}" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" th:field="*{experienceDate}"/>
     <input type="hidden" th:field="*{rating}"/>
     <!-- ADD ALL THE OTHER FIELDS THAT ARE PART OF THE OBJECT -->
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This will hide your object data from user but when they click on submit, it will send the object data as required (rather than having empty form sent as you have it currently).

Comment: Okay that makes sense. When I initially hit the web page I am sending in a "borrower" object from my controller that you can see I use in order to access all of the borrower's individual experiences. Would there be any way that I could send that entire borrower object back to my controller once the submit button is pressed? Or am I only able to submit inputs?

Comment: Unless you expose the borrower then no (generate input for each field). You can do this tho with webflow but thats a another bag of chips there that can cause more problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "expose the borrower"?

Comment: You are trying to send borrower object, which means you have to expose the borrower object. i.e. display each field for the borrower object within the form so that when submitted Spring can bind it to borrower object.

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying! Thank you for the help! You have definitely helped make some more Spring/Thymeleaf capabilities clear to me

Comment: No worries. Please accept answer if it meets your needs

Comment: @Aeseir
I have a similar requirement and I can't seem to make it work. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086540/how-to-send-object-that-is-retrived-in-a-get-request-to-a-post-requet-spring-b) It's pretty much what I want to do but there's no answer. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

As @Aeseir's answer, you need to pay attention to the `th:object` and `th:field`
The `field` can be int, double, String, List and the object should have getter and setter for its field.
In this case

```
public class Experience{
     String field;
     List<String> list;
     //getter() and setter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What @Aeseir said it has helped me, but instead of :

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{experienceDate}"/>
```

I needed to use:

```
<input type="hidden" th:value="${experience.experienceDate}" name="someName"/>
```