# How to pass object from th:each loop to controller

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have form and corresponding controller to which list of objects is passed. After that this list is redirected as an attribute to another method and displayed in a website. After that I would like to pass object from this list via form in a carSearchResult.html file to controller. I was trying to do like it is described here [Spring and Thymeleaf: Sending an object to a controller from a th:each table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926136/spring-and-thymeleaf-sending-an-object-to-a-controller-from-a-theach-table) but it does not work properly. It is sending an object to controller but with fields property and model set as blank (but they are not null).

searchCar form

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/user/searchCar}" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="hatch" /> Hatchback <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="sedan" /> Sedan <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="combi" /> Kombi <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="sport" /> Sport <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="cabrio" /> Cabrio <br/>
    <input type="text" name="dailyPrice" placeholder="Price" /> <br/>
    <input type="date" name="dateOfRent" placeholder="Date of rent" /> <br/>
    <input type="date" name="dateOfReturn" placeholder="Date of return" /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Show" />
</form>
```

Controller method for searchCar post request

```
@PostMapping("/user/searchCar")
public String searchCar(Model model, @RequestParam String type, @RequestParam double dailyPrice,
        @RequestParam Date dateOfRent, @RequestParam Date dateOfReturn, RedirectAttributes redirectAttr) {
    List<Car> allCarsList = carDao.getAllCars(type, dailyPrice, dateOfRent, dateOfReturn);
    redirectAttr.addFlashAttribute("carList", allCarsList);
    return "redirect:/user/carSearchResults";
}
```

Method where list is redirected

```
@GetMapping("/user/carSearchResults")
public String showCarSearchResults(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
    return "user/carSearchResults";
}
```

Form where list is displayed

```
<div th:each="car: ${carList}">
    <h3 th:text="${car.producer}"></h3>
    <h3 th:text="${car.model}"></h3>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/user/showCarDetails}" method="post" th:object="${car}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{producer}" /> <br/>            
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{model}" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Show" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Method to which I want to send object from th:each loop

```
@PostMapping("/user/showCarDetails")
public String showCarDetails(@ModelAttribute Car car) {
    System.out.println(car);
    return "user/showCarDetails";
}
```

After printing information about car in console I receive object below. It looks like it is passed but with parameters as a blank space. Can anyone help me? Many thanks.

```
Car [id=null, producer=, model=, seatsNumber=null, type=null, registrationNumber=null, dailyPrice=null, description=null]
```

**EDIT**

I have changed the form. Option with th:attr and th:value works but I do not really understand why th:field does not work and what is the difference between them. As I understand from documentation th:value is some kind of older version of th:field?

```
<div th:each="car: ${carList}" th:object="${car}">
    <h3 th:text="*{producer}"></h3>
    <h3 th:text="*{model}"></h3>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/user/showCarDetails}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:value="*{producer}" name="producer" /> <br/>       <!-- It works -->
        <input type="hidden" th:attr="value=*{producer}" name="producer" /> <br/>  <!-- It works -->        
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{producer}" />                             <!-- It does not work -->
        <input type="submit" value="Pokaż" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't pass an object from thymeleaf to a controller. only from the controller to thymeleaf. You send something to a controller via a POST call, from the HTML form. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: But via @ModelAttribute annotation I receive object from parameters which were sent via POST call?

Answer (score 1):

[`th:object` works differently when you use it on a `<form>`, vs. when you use it other places](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form).  When you use it in a form, it expects it to resolve to a single variable on the model.  You cannot use it with a temporary variable (like `{$car}` -- which isn't on the model, it's just a temporary variable created by`th:each`) because the attribute just isn't built to work like that.

`th:field` generates both the `value` and `name` tags -- but again, it has to work within the same limitations as `th:object`.  The reason manually adding `name` and `value` attributes work, is because they happen to line up with what spring is expecting in a post and it's able to create the object based on the names.

As for how to solve the original problem... I think you have two options:

1. Create a command object which has a `List` of `Car`s as a property.  That way you can use the `th:object` and `th:field` properties.  You'll have to have the submit button to supply which car is being edited.
2. Continue manually creating the name and value fields like you already are.

Comment: Ok, I think it is a little bit more clear for me now. To sum up: `<input type="hidden" th:value="*{producer}" name="producer" />` - this works because we are taking this temporary variable `{$car}` and assign to it producer field? That's why Spring is able to create a Car object?